# Determine the image and area of the unit disk under linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

Determine the image and area of the unit disk D = {($x$, $y$) | $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1$ } under the linear transformation *T*: **R**$^2$ $\rightarrow$ **R**$^2$ defined by T([, ]) = $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{bmatrix}$

So far I've taken the inverse of A = $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$ and I've gotten $\frac{1}{2}$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
-\sqrt{3} & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. Not sure how to proceed with the solution, however.

Comment: Taken inverse of the matrix, but not sure where to go from there

Comment: Always add your attempts to your question ...It's better in order to get answers and hints.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user. I didn't know the protocol, I'll make sure I do that next time

Comment: Area of the image is $2\pi$ and the image is an ellipse.

Comment: @La'QuaviousJackson, read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @SarGe Thanks for the info !

Comment: No problem..You're welcome.

Comment: @JCAA How did you calculate that? I understand that area of unit disk will be , but how do you know the image is an ellipse?

Comment: @La'QuaviousJackson, substitute $$x=\frac{X}{2}+Y\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\\ y=-X\sqrt 3+Y$$ in the original equation.

Comment: @SarGe You don't have to distribute the 1/2 when calculating the inverse?

Comment: @SarGe Or wait...is this just det(A) • area of disk formula? So det(A) = 2 and area of unit disk is , so area(T(D)) is just 2?

Comment: You do not need to calculate much, just the determinant of the matrix. The rest applies to any invertible linear transformation.

Comment: You got two answers Do you need anything else. If not, accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose the rotation through $π/3$ with $(x,y)\mapsto(2x,y)$.

The former "is" $\begin{pmatrix}1/2&-\sqrt3/2\\\sqrt3/2&1/2\end{pmatrix}$; the latter $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

The rotation preserves area and shape.    The other one takes the unit circle to the ellipse $ (\dfrac x2)^2+y^2=1$.    But that has area $2π$ (by this [Show that the Area of image = Area of object $\cdot |\det(T)|$? Where $T$ is a linear transformation from $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2074672/403337), or  a little calculus).

Answer (score 0):

With linear transformations, the area of the image of a figure is the area of the figure times the determinant of the transformation. The area of a unit circle is $\pi$ and the determinant of your matrix is $2$. So the area of the image of a unit circle is $2\pi$:

[Show that the Area of image = Area of object $\cdot |\det(T)|$? Where $T$ is a linear transformation from $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074672/show-that-the-area-of-image-area-of-object-cdot-dett-where-t-is-a-l)

The image of a quadric under a non-singular linear transformation is a quadric. The image of a bounded figure is a bounded figure. The only bounded quadrics are ellipses (follows from the classification of quadrics). Hence the image of a unit circle is an ellipse.