# Why is the Jacobian matrix so useful?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, jacobian

I am a first year undergraduate and I always see the Jacobian crop up in some many places, e.g., integration, solving systems of equations, analysis and so many more places. I was wondering, what makes it so useful?

Comment: You have seen it in many places but you wonder why it is useful? It seems like you can solve your question yourself.

Comment: Well yes, I know what it does. But I was looking for someone to provide some reason as to what inherent property it has that allows it to be so useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I think that's the same as asking why the *derivative* is useful, which I'd assume you'd have an easier time intuiting.

In some sense, the Jacobian *is* the derivative of a multivariate vector function. I.e. if $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, what is the derivative of $f$? The Jacobian encodes the derivatives of all components of $f$ with respect to all variables, and thus serves as its derivative. Notice that we recover the classic derivative when $n=m=1$ and the gradient when $n=1$.
Dynamical systems, for example, can be treated as such a function, and 
linearized that way, using the property of the derivative (and Jacobian) as providing the best local linear approximation to a function.

The fact that it is structured as an array is also useful, as it lets it be used very naturally with tensors or matrices and vectors, so that useful equations and identities in $\mathbb{R}$ generalize in notationally pleasant ways to higher dimensions (and even to manifolds) via the Jacobian.

Comment: Indeed, the Jacobian matrix is the differential (a.k.a. total derivative) of the function expressed as a matrix.

Comment: Thank you!! This was exactly what I was looking for - didn't appreciate this link. I now also why it is used in double/triple integrals to make substitutions when we compare to the easy integration by substitution case :)

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove You're welcome. The determinant of the Jacobian has the additional property that [its determinant measures the change in area/volume that comes from a coordinate change](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923303/why-is-the-determinant-of-the-jacobian-the-change-of-volume-factor-that-comes-fr), which is partly why it shows up in integral and tensor transformations. :)