# Variation of a functional increment second definition supposition

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

In Gelfand and Formin Calculus of Variation, the increment of the functional is

$$ \Delta J [h] = J[y+h] - J[y]$$

it is supposed that the increment can also be written in the form of

$$\Delta J[h] = \varphi [h] + \varepsilon ||h||$$

however I do not see how the 2nd definition of the functional increment picks up a $ \varepsilon ||h||$ term.
What is the significance of the $\varepsilon ||h||$ term in the 2nd definition.

It is confusing what does the $\varepsilon$ multiply $||h||$ mean in the context of a functional

Hope I could get this confusion clarified, as it was not explained the reason why this supposition was made.

Comment: See [Motivation for the differentiability of a function $f:D\subset\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3802166/568204). There OP asks about finite-dimensional spaces, but the definition (and motivation and intuition) are virtually unchanged in the general Banach space setting. Or, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3802105/568204) for the general definition. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3298644/568204) is some extra motivation. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3785633/568204) is an example of using the definition to prove the chain rule.

Comment: As you'll hopefully recognize after reading those answers, the key concept of differential calculus is linear approximations: "actual change = linear part + 'small' error term". That's what the $\epsilon(h)\,\|h\|$ term represents.

Comment: I think the OP's source of confusion is notational. Gelfand & Formin (or rather Silverman) do not make the dependence of $\epsilon$ on $h$ clear in the text.

Comment: thanks @peek-a-boo I now understand that the $\varepsilon ||h||$ is the linear error term, but how does $\varepsilon$ multiplied with $||h||$ gives the dimension of an error so to speak ?

Comment: It is because if you take the error $\epsilon(h) \|h\|$ and divide by $\|h\|$ (which is also what we do in single variable calculus; differential calculus is all avout first order approzimations) and take a limit, you get 0. This condition is giving a quantitative description of how small the error must be in order to say that a function is differentiable.