# New coordinates in a double integral theoretic question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\iint_Df(x,y)dxdy = \iint_\omega f(g(s,t))\cdot|\det(J)|dtds$$

Where $J$ is Jacobi matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}x_s \quad x_t \\y_s \quad y_t   \end{bmatrix}$

My question is why do we need Jacobi matrix in the first place? What exactly is going on when we are doing this. I did a couple of examples and know how to use it, but I still don't quite understand how it works. What would we use if we would want to calculate a triple integral or "$n$" integral. What about only a single integral, would we still need the Jacobi matrix?

Comment: The key insight comes from linear transformations and that their absolute value determinants give the "scale factor" for areas/volumes. The Jacobian determinant is there in all dimensions. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3239222/568204) of mine for some heuristic remarks which you may find helpful. Also, [littleO's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/464972/568204) gives  more details, regarding Riemann sums, than my linked answer, so you may find that useful. But in any case, you MUST understand things at the special case when $g$ is linear first.

Comment: It is the multivariable version of the derivative that occurs in $du = g'(x)dx$ when you carried out the 1-var substitution $u=g(x)$ back in the first semester of calculus.